# Is it possible to declare a nested type alias using a forward declared class in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, using, forward-declaration, type-alias

I'm breaking up a circular include dependency by forward declaring the class in its respective header, however that puts a small wrinkle in the existing convention of using a type alias inside of a class:

```cpp
#include <memory>

class C {
 public:
  using Ptr = std::shared_ptr<C>;
};
```

Ideally it'd be possible to do something like:

```cpp
#include <memory>

class C;
using C::Ptr = std::shared_ptr<C>;
```

But that's not possible because `C` isn't a complete type (yet). I realize it's possible to create an alias `using CPtr = std::shared_ptr<C>;`, but I was hoping I was missing something obvious using `typename` or some other keyword that would establish `C` as a complete-enough type for the purpose of creating a nested type alias.

Comment: Have you tried a typedef with a pointer?  `typedef C* ForwardedCClass;`?

Comment: `C` is always a "valid identifier" and is a valid "typename" immediately after the forward declaration, but not a "complete type" until the class definition.

Comment: Thank you. Updated the wording in the question to be more correct.

Comment: No, this isn't possible, a member type has to be declared in the class definition, otherwise you could add new members to third-party classes, which would then give you access to private members

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot put something inside of a class except by actually writing it inside the class definition.

It's not an issue of whether `C` is a complete type or not. It's simply that C++ does not have any syntax that allows a name to be added to a class scope (or any scope) other than by actually writing it in that scope.

Comment: I was afraid someone would say that.